# How can I use a EaselJS.Bitmap instance to populate a HTMLImageElement?

Tags: createjs, easeljs

I'm creating a help page for a game I've developed in CreateJS. The help page is done in plain html. I would like to populate some Image elements in the help page with data from EaselJS.bitmap instances originating in the game. What's the best approach for this?

Answer (score 1):

The Bitmap instances use HTMLImageElements to draw.

If you already have Bitmap instances generated, you can access `bmpInstance.image`. This is probably the best approach if you create your Bitmaps with a string path.

```
var bmp = new createjs.Bitmap("path/to/image.jpg");
document.body.appendChild(bmp.image);
```

If you are preloading using PreloadJS, you can get the result the same way as you use to populate a Bitmap:

```
var img = queue.getResult("imageId"); // <-- That is an image element
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! However, the bitmaps originate in a spritesheet, so I assume using bmp.image would produce the whole spritesheet image? I'm considering adding the bitmap to a canvas sized to fit the bitmap and populating the DOM with that instead of an HTMLImageElement. Would that make sense or is there a better approach?

Comment: If you are using a Sprite/SpriteSheet, then you can look up spriteSheetInstance.images (which is an array)